# I can't change the image in my website to responsive

Tags: html, css, image, minimize, responsiveness

I'm working on my activity website and I currently have problem with the image in my about section with its responsiveness. I'm trying to change my image where when I minimize the browser, the image will also adjust to smaller but I can't find way to adjust it and make it responsive. Kindly help me.

```css
 #abouts {
   background: #07414C;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
 
.about{
    padding: 100px 0px;
    background-color: #033541;
}
.about .about-picture img {
    width: 430px;
}
.about-text{
    width: 550px;
}
.main{
    width: 1130px;
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.about-text h2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.about-text h5{
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.about-text p{
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .about .main {
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
   }
   .about .about-picture img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
    .about .main .about-text h5  {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 1.2rem;
      padding-left: 1.2rem;
   }
   .about .main .about-text h2  {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 1.8rem;
      padding-left: 1.8rem;
   }
   .about .main .about-text p  {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: justify;
      padding-right: 2.8rem;
      padding-left: 2.8rem;
   }

 }
```

```html
<!----about start---->
<div id = "abouts">
    <section class="about">
        <div class="main">
            <div class = "about-picture">
            <img src="aboutpic.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="about-text">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <h5>word 1<span>, word 2, and word 3</span></h5>
                <p>Name, age, place. school where im studying. things that i love. motto.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-width` should be defined in pixel, not the simple `width`.

And it's enough to make it fluid, no need for extra media query code.

```
 .about .about-picture img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 430px;
}
```